# Can I copy timezone file from RHEL 6.6 to RHEL 6.5?

Tags: datetime, redhat

I'm running 2 servers one RHEL 6.6 and another 6.5, I've changed the timezone on both to 'Australia/Sydney'

But when I issue the date command

RHEL 6.5 is showing as xx:xx:xx EST 2015

RHEL 6.6 is showing as xx:xx:ss  AEDT 2015

Issue is both are showing same time but zone is different, I want 'AEDT' on both servers.

**Can I copy the timezone file **/use/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Sydney from one RHEL 6.6 server to RHEL 6.5** ?**

Answer (score 1):

Just use `tzselect` to get the correct timezone.

```
$ tzselect 
Please identify a location so that time zone rules can be set correctly.
Please select a continent, ocean, "coord", or "TZ".
 1) Africa
 2) Americas
 3) Antarctica
 4) Arctic Ocean
 5) Asia
 6) Atlantic Ocean
 7) Australia
 8) Europe
 9) Indian Ocean
10) Pacific Ocean
11) coord - I want to use geographical coordinates.
12) TZ - I want to specify the time zone using the Posix TZ format.
#? 7
Please select one of the following time zone regions.
1) Lord Howe Island                      8) Queensland - most locations
2) Macquarie Island                      9) Queensland - Holiday Islands
3) Tasmania - most locations            10) South Australia
4) Tasmania - King Island               11) Northern Territory
5) Victoria                             12) Western Australia - most locations
6) New South Wales - most locations     13) Western Australia - Eucla area
7) New South Wales - Yancowinna
#? 6

The following information has been given:

        Australia
        New South Wales - most locations

Therefore TZ='Australia/Sydney' will be used.
Local time is now:      Thu Jan  8 15:45:46 AEDT 2015.
Universal Time is now:  Thu Jan  8 04:45:46 UTC 2015.
Is the above information OK?
1) Yes
2) No
#? 1

You can make this change permanent for yourself by appending the line
        TZ='Australia/Sydney'; export TZ
to the file '.profile' in your home directory; then log out and log in again.

Here is that TZ value again, this time on standard output so that you
can use the /usr/bin/tzselect command in shell scripts:
Australia/Sydney
```